# How to effectively manage 1341 saved links on pinboard?

Tags: macos, services, bookmarks

I've 'recently' started using Pinboard + Shiori (OSX link searching app, syncs with your pinboard account) as link bookmarking and searching setup. Searching works incredibly well with Shiori.

My problem is that i had imported around 1230 links that were living in google chrome's bookmarks at the time of account creation. I now find myself wanting to review and manage these links. However, doing this one-by-one as offered on pinboard kind of sucks, it's too slow. 
I would like to do this with more raw power. For example see a list of screenshots of sites pulled from my bookmarks - or better yet: LIST the ones that are broken, so i can search for them and re-bookmark the correct URLS.

How can i do this while still using pinboard? Should i export everything, edit it in another (more powerful) program and import it back into pinboard? What is the best link sorting / management / tagging application out there for Mac OSX (10.9 Mavericks)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

export as xml and use excel to edit it .